# Solution of ODE with second order boundary condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I am looking to find the $~c~$ value in the following analytical solution of given ODE,

$y''+\gamma y'=0~~~~~~~~~~$  [ODE]

$y=c e^{-\gamma x} ~~~~~~~~~~$ [The analytical solution]

with help of following boundary conditions

$\alpha y''(0)+\beta y'(0)+y(0)=0~~~~~and~~~ y(\infty)=0~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are all constants.

Comment: By default, it is the zero function, $c=0$. In special cases every $c$ gives a solution.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Could you tell us what you tried so far and what you do know about this problem? That may help the community to provide a useful answer.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann
But that solution must satisfy the both boundary conditions.

Comment: @HSN, I am trying to find such solution which satisfy the both conditions. But $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ are not good enough to satisfy first condition. Even though, I tried to find the solution at $\gamma=1$.

Comment: Everything is homogeneous, so the zero function is always a solution. If $αγ^2-βγ+1=0$, then you get more solutions.